# addnig a image as water mark into a gif image

Tags: php, imagemagick, animated-gif, watermark

I want to add water mark image see the below image for water mark.

[image: http://gif-king/test/WFr1K.png]

see the below gif image

[image: http://gif-king/test/h8Hjm.gif]

for that I used image magic

```
<?php exec("convert h8Hjm.gif null: WFr1K.png  -gravity Center -layers composite -layers optimize animation.gif"); ?>
<img src="animation.gif" />
```

But that won't work.

But I read the below forum that should work with the above code.
Please check the forum link: 
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=24925&sid=c539164897d03fefa0b4dac11568f6f8&p=107530#p107530

Please help me how to run this.

Comment: @Brice that is already working in the reference http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=24925&sid=c539164897d03fefa0b4dac11568f6f8&p=107530#p107530

my question is that why not working for me with same code

Comment: I did not get that sorry..I'll remove my previous comment. I think you should update your question with more information about what the problem is, the output or some kind of error messages for instance.